# Unable to connect MySQL on system start in Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: mysql, .net-4.5, mysql-connector, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a Windows service (using .NET framework 4.5) installed on a Windows 2012 R2 machine. I have MySQL connector 6.9.7 and MySQL 5.6.25

When my service is started I am getting following error.

> Authentication to host 'xxx.xx.x.xx' for user 'yyyyy' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Reading from the stream has failed. ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Reading from the stream has failed. ---> System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Attempted to read past the end of the stream.

or sometimes:

> Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

If I restart the service in a while all seems to work properly. Any idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Migrating OP's solution from the question to an answer:</sub>

> After further investigation we have found that our database version was 5.6.25. We have tried same connectivity with our old db 5.5.16 and we didn't face the same issue, so it looks like issue is the database itself. Our new database is installed on a Linux machine.